Suppose primes $p,q\mid |G|$ with $p<q$. For $|x|=p$, does $x^G=(x^{-1})^G\iff p=2$?
The Question:

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose primes $p,q\mid |G|$ with $p<q$. Let $x\in G$ such that $|x|=p$. Does $x^G=(x^{-1})^G$ if and only if $p=2$?

Here $g^G$ is the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$.
Thoughts:
$(\Leftarrow)$
If $p=2$, then $x=x^{-1}$.
$(\Rightarrow)$
Cauchy's Theorem gives an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$.

Perhaps we could state the theorem contrapositively about $p$-groups . . .

What is $x^G?$ please.

The conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$, @softtostadaburrito. Thank you for pointing that out.

Ok.  Makes sense I guess,  because come to think of it I've seen $x^g=gxg^{-1}.$

However (and maybe this is what you thought of) if $p$ is a prime and a group has a unique element of order $p$, then $p=2$.

If $x^g=x^{-1}$, and both $x$ and $g$ have finite order, then either $x$ has order $2$, or $g$ have even order. For if $x\neq x^{-1}$, then $g\notin C_G(x)$, but $\langle g^2\rangle \subseteq C_G(x)$, so $g\notin \langle g^2\rangle$. So if $G$ is finite, and $x$ is not of order $2$ and conjugate to $x^{-1}$, then there is an element $g$ of order a power of $2$ such that $x^g=x^{-1}$, but I think that's the best you can do.

@softtostadaburrito It's actually $x^g = g^{-1}xg$, and ${}^gx=gxg^{-1}$. That allows $(x^g)^h = x^{gh}$ (whereas $x^g=gxg^{-1}$ would mean $(x^g)^h = x^{hg}$).

In the symmetric group $S_n$ each element is conjugate to its inverse.

Oh, of course! I was reminded of this fact recently too! Thank you.
